# Подключение к БД Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

Есть БД на удаленном сервере. Пытаюсь подключиться так

```
db.host = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.4.113:1521:med
db.user = meduser
db.password = 123456
```

Класс для подключения

```
public class DBConnection {
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("db.properties"))) {
            properties.load(in);
        }

        String host = properties.getProperty("db.host");
        String user = properties.getProperty("db.user");
        String password = properties.getProperty("db.password");

        return DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
    }
}
```

Вот что выдает при выполнении запроса

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: таблица или
>   представление пользователя не существует
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:876)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1498)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо взять из TNS имя хоста, в вашем случае IP, порт и SID (считайте, что это имя базы данных). Имея эти параметры вы сможете построить URL строку подключения к серверу Oracle. См. [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcthin.htm). Например, `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HOST>:<PORT>:<SID>", "<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>");`

Comment: А как в файле db.properties это прописать так?  db.host = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.4.113:1521:med
db.user = meduser
db.password = 123456

Comment: Я бы хотел настройки подключения к БД в файле db.properties оставить. Попробовал так написать мне выдало ошибку   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: таблица или представление пользователя не существует

Comment: Если вам выдало такую ошибку, то значит к базе вы уже подключились. Проблема в вашем SELECT-е, неверно указано имя таблицы. Скорее всего таблица находится вне персональной схемы пользователя, надо указывать имя таблицы вместе с именем схемы через точку 'SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE`

Comment: Да я вот тоже прочитал тут другой вопрос и понял что нужно указать схему. А как узнать имя схемы? Дело в том, что БД ставил не я.

Comment: Варианта два -1. спросить у того, кто делал эту базу или хотя бы знает как она устроена, 2 - залезть внутрь с помощью какого-нибудь GUI, например [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) и поискать нужную таблицу самостоятельно.

Comment: У меня есть доступ к БД по PL/SQL developer. Как называется таблица?

Comment: Ну, тоже годится. Там вроде было где-то что-типа "Найти объект базы данных..." попробуйте поищите. Если не находится, то, скорее всего, у вашего пользователя нет доступа к этой таблице.

Comment: Спасибо попробую найти